# Using a View as SubView in different Views WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View - which is a UserControl - that shows different information and gets updated by its corresponding ViewModel.

Now I want to use this View in different other Views, which are UserControls as well.

I tried different approaches like using ResourceDictionaries and other stuff, but I couldn´t get a satisfying result.

Comment: *"I tried different approaches"* - have you tried to add `<local:SomeUserControl .../>` into another user control xaml? Specifically for MVVM: same but in control/data template?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put a `ContentControl` in views that are importing your view and set the `ContentControl`'s `Content` to the given view